# How to speed up camel routes

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm working on a service (spring-boot) that takes a list of ids, one-by-one fetches objects from DB, aggregates those objects into batches, and then saves them somewhere else. Currently, the batch size after aggregation is ~50 objects which is roughly 10 objects per second being sent to the aggregation route. Now I'm trying to understand how I can speed up my routes or at least get some idea where is the bottleneck.

This is the bean that sends requests concurrently to **direct:findObject**

```
@Produce(uri = "direct:findObject")
private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

public void send() {
    List<Long> listOfIDs = someService.getIDList(); //1000000 ids in the list
    listOfIDs.parallelStream().forEach(producerTemplate::sendBody);
}
```

My camel routes:

```
    from(direct:findObject)
            .bean(objectDaoBean)
            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson, MyObject.class)
            .to("direct:aggregator");

    from("direct:aggregator")
            .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson, MyObject.class)
            .aggregate(constant(true), new GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy())
            .parallelProcessing()
            .completionInterval(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5))
            .completionSize(1000)
            .marshal(new GsonDataFormat(new TypeToken<List<MyObject>>() {}.getType()))
            .to("direct:bulkSave");

    from("direct:bulkSave")
            .unmarshal(new GsonDataFormat(new TypeToken<List<MyObject>>() {}.getType()))
            .bean(bulkSaveBean);
```

Any help or insights on how I can make the whole process faster is greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
I've managed to increase the overral performance (at least x10) with changes propoused by @Fábio Carmo Santos

application.properties:

```
camel.threadpool.pool-size=10
camel.threadpool.max-pool-size=400
camel.threadpool.max-queue-size=-1
```

Updated producer:

```
@Produce("direct:splitter")
private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

public void sendList() {
    List<Long> listOfIDs = getIDList(); //1000000 ids in the list
    producerTemplate.sendBody(listOfIDs);
}
```

Modified camel routes:

```
   from("direct:splitter")
            .split(body())
            .parallelProcessing()
            .bean(new DaoBean()) //fetch an object by id from db here
            .to("direct:aggregator");

    from("direct:aggregator")
            .aggregate(body(), new GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy())
            .parallelProcessing()
            .completionInterval(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5))
            .completionSize(1000)
            .to("direct:bulkSave");

    from("direct:bulkSave")
            .bean(new SaveBean());
```

Before I had in logs:

```
Saving... Batch size 30
Saving... Batch size 45
Saving... Batch size 41
Saving... Batch size 53
Saving... Batch size 47
Saving... Batch size 50
```

And overral execution time was at least hours (never waited until it finishes)

Now it's way better and faster

```
Saving... Batch size 499
Saving... Batch size 1000
Saving... Batch size 401
Saving... Batch size 1000
Saving... Batch size 257
Saving... Batch size 1000
```

Comment: By reading your code, I wonder why you're marshaling/unmarshaling when forwarding message to/from your own routes. It's a little bit expensive; it seems you don't need that.

Comment: Due to my limited knowledge of camel, I couldn't make it work without marshaling/unmarshaling objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the IDs distinct when you `getIDList()`? If not, you could distinct them just to eliminate duplicated IDs. Only you can decide whether it makes sense.

Why don't you send route the list and let Camel split it for you? The streaming option in [Split](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/split-eip.html) is very helpful. PS.: Only by using this in a recent project, I managed to reduce the processing time from 1m30s to 15s!

Take a look at the [Threading Model](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/threading-model.html) as well. Maybe, you'll feel like editing the thread pool profile. It defaults to 20 at max.

There are actually many ways of handling it. You could also page your searches by partitioning your collection, then enrich your Exchange by getting multiple records (let's say 200 per poll) at once from DB instead of fetching one by one, using an AggregationStrategy if needed or just splitting the search result.

Comment: All IDs in the list are always unique. So you are suggesting not to send IDs one by one to the direct:findObject route but the whole list and let camel (splitter?) take care of it? I'll try that

Comment: Exactly! At first, you could try that. I suppose you'd make it faster by partitioning the whole list of IDs and retrieving multiple records at once from DB.